# automatically assign value to a field in a laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am working with laravel and in one of my models I need to automatically assign the value to a field (of type date) every time a record is created, as I am just starting with laravel, I do not do this, since I try with a mutator:

```
public function setApprovedDateAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['approved_date'] = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

but it doesn't work for me, because I think that the mutator as its name says it changes the value that I am sending for this field, in my case I need to add one automatically every time I create a new record, so how can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at [eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#events) this is best done in the `creating` event

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @apokryfos mentioned in comment, best would be do it over creating event. 
Here what you should do, let's say your table is `subscriptions` with field `subscriptions.approved_date` and model is `Subscription`, here is very clean way of what you can do to achieve issued result:

1.
`php artisan make:observer SubscriptionObserver --model=Subscription`

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Subscription;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class SubscriptionObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the subscription "creating" event.
     *
     * @param Subscription $subscription
     * @return void
     */
    public function creating(Subscription $subscription)
    {
        $subscription->approved_date = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}
```

*Note: I added `creating()` method, it isn't there by default.*

2.
`php artisan make:provider SubscriptionServiceProvider`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Observers\SubscriptionObserver;
use App\Subscription;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SubscriptionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Subscription::observe(SubscriptionObserver::class);
    }
}
```

*Notice line in `boot()` method.*

3.
Include provider into provider list of `config/app.php`

```
<?php

return [

    // other elements

    /*
    |------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        // other providers

        App\Providers\SubscriptionServiceProvider::class,

    ],
];
```

All this can be skipped and done in `boot()` model's method but shown way is easier to maintain for me.

Comment: excellent answer, I was reading this in the documentation although I did not understand some things, I already have something more clear. One more doubt when you say that I can register that provider in the boot, do you mean the method in AppServiceProvider?

Comment: If you listen model's observer in AppServiceProvider, you can skip steps 2 and 3. 
You can do it in AppServiceProvider but I like to keep things separated this way.